# Rails 3 select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Product model, and I need one my `options_from_collection_for_select` to be populated from one of the columns from my products model, however I need the `options_for_select` to be unique, and not all values from that column at repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Rails provides methods for selecting by unique column values, it's faster to directly fetch unique results using the `find_by_sql` model method.

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
@unique_products = Product.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY unique_column")

# app/views/products/_form.html.erb
<%= select_tag 'product', options_from_collection_for_select(@unique_products, 'id', 'name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a unique list of a specific column on your products model:

```
Product.uniq.pluck(:size)
```

Comment: I tried this and get an exception: `undefined method dept for "":String`, however I can retrieve it in console.

Answer (score 0):

[select_tag(name, option_tags = nil, options = {})](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)

```
@uniq_products = Product.group(:column_name)

select_tag "product", options_from_collection_for_select(@uniq_products, "id", "<column_name>")
```